# How to perform a translation to an object a certain amount of times in Python?

Tags: python, object, translation

So I am having trouble coming up with a solution to this problem.  I want to have an object and the user inputs a number.  The number determines how many times the object gets translated over a constant distance and a constant direction.
                                                                                                                       Now I am going to give an example of the problem.  The user inputs the number 2.  The software takes the object and creates a copy of it translated over a certain distance.  But the user wants this to happen 2 times so the software translates the copy over a certain distance so there is now the original object, the translated copy of the object and the translated copy of the copy of the object.  Now I am afraid the software may interpret the input as make 2 copies of the original object and translate the object.  Now the translated objects are in the same place instead of all separated by a constant distance.  Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: By object I mean a real world object like a ball or an atom that can be moved in certain directions.

Comment: Then show us the code. We need to know the methods of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't give all of the details, I'm assuming that there's a function translate as a part of the object that translates it the desired amount.  Based off of that, a quick thought of what it would look like is

```
def translate_n_times(n, distance, object):
    cur_object = object
    obj_list = []
    obj_list.append(object)
    for i in range(0,n):
        new_object = copy.deepcopy(cur_object)
        new_object.translate(distance)
        obj_list.append(new_object)
        cur_object = new_object
    return obj_list
```

It's not perfect, but it should be an outline for what you're trying to do.  by keeping a reference to the object each time, you make sure to always translate based off of the last copy.

Comment: Thanks! This really helps I just have one question, what does **for i in range(0,n):** mean?

Comment: for i in range (0,n) means that this will iterate through this process n times; the first time, i will be equal to 0, then 1, up to (n-1).  As python doesn't have traditional for loops as you would see in c, for loops that aren't iterating through a list often take this form.

Comment: What does it have to do with the next lines of code you wrote?

Comment: This means that the code that is indented there will be run n number of times.  Because of this, it will always translate off of the most recently made object.  I would recommend reading [Python's explanation of loops](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html), as it seems this is a new concept to you and mastering loops is very important for programming in Python (or any language for that matter).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I just started python and am still getting use to it.